# NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, python-3.x, k-means, recommendation-engine

I was building wine recommendation system using k means approach in django. I made cluster module in admin and added 3 clusters manually. However, when I am trying to recommend wine to logged in user I get this error.Can you please help:

```
AttributeError at /reviews/recommendation/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I am getting error in line:

```
User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first().name
```

here is the code for view.py

```
@login_required
def user_recommendation_list(request):
    # get request user reviewed wines
    user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=request.user.username).prefetch_related('wine')
    user_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, user_reviews))

    # get request user cluster name (just the first one righ now)
    try:
        user_cluster_name = \
            User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first().name
    except: # if no cluster assigned for a user, update clusters
        update_clusters()
        user_cluster_name = \
            User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first().name

    # get usernames for other memebers of the cluster
    user_cluster_other_members = \
        Cluster.objects.get(name=user_cluster_name).users \
            .exclude(username=request.user.username).all()
    other_members_usernames = set(map(lambda x: x.username, user_cluster_other_members))

    # get reviews by those users, excluding wines reviewed by the request user
    other_users_reviews = \
        Review.objects.filter(user_name__in=other_members_usernames) \
            .exclude(wine__id__in=user_reviews_wine_ids)
    other_users_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, other_users_reviews))

    # then get a wine list including the previous IDs, order by rating
    wine_list = sorted(
        list(Wine.objects.filter(id__in=other_users_reviews_wine_ids)), 
        key=lambda x: x.average_rating, 
        reverse=True
    )

    return render(
        request, 
        'reviews/user_recommendation_list.html', 
        {'username': request.user.username,'wine_list': wine_list}
        )
```

and here is the code for suggestions.py

```
from .models import Review, Wine, Cluster
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix, csr_matrix
import numpy as np

def update_clusters():
    num_reviews = Review.objects.count()
    update_step = ((num_reviews/100)+1) * 5
    if num_reviews % update_step == 0: # using some magic numbers here, sorry...
        # Create a sparse matrix from user reviews
        all_user_names = map(lambda x: x.username, User.objects.only("username"))
        all_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, Review.objects.only("wine")))
        num_users = len(all_user_names)
        ratings_m = dok_matrix((num_users, max(all_wine_ids)+1), dtype=np.float32)
        for i in range(num_users): # each user corresponds to a row, in the order of all_user_names
            user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=all_user_names[i])
            for user_review in user_reviews:
                ratings_m[i,user_review.wine.id] = user_review.rating

        # Perform kmeans clustering
        k = int(num_users / 10) + 2
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
        clustering = kmeans.fit(ratings_m.tocsr())

        # Update clusters
        Cluster.objects.all().delete()
        new_clusters = {i: Cluster(name=i) for i in range(k)}
        for cluster in new_clusters.values(): # clusters need to be saved before refering to users
            cluster.save()
        for i,cluster_label in enumerate(clustering.labels_):
            new_clusters[cluster_label].users.add(User.objects.get(username=all_user_names[i]))
```

Comment: Are you sure this `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first()` returns something?

Comment: I have no idea how to debug this problem but i guess it doesnt....else the error wouldn't have popped

Comment: Have a look using the `shell`. Make the queries and see what comes out.

Answer (score -2):

When you are going to add data in the cluster table at that time you need to insert your current logged in username. For instance,

1. jadianes, carlos, and lluis
2. <**username**>, teus, yasset
3. ...